# error build_call

Tags: polkadot, ink, smart-contract

```rs
#[ink(message)]
pub fn get_flip2_buill_call(&mut self, token_contract_address: AccountId, account_id: AccountId )-> i32 {
    let my_return_value = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
        .call(token_contract_address)
        .gas_limit(0)
        .transferred_value(0)
        .exec_input(
            ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!("flip"))).push_arg(1i32)
        )
        .returns::<i32>()
        .invoke();

   my_return_value
}
```

[image]

Comment: The original post is completely a mess.